# How to retrieve a term tree for a specific vocabulary given the machine name?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Retrieving a term tree for a specific vocabulary  in Drupal 8 requires the vocabulary ID. I can find no function/method/service that will return the vocabulary entity given the machine name, in order to get the vocabulary ID.

How do I get a vocabulary ID from its machine name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*vid* is the vocabulary machine name, in Drupal 8. You just need to pass the the string you have to [`TermStorage::loadTree()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermStorage.php/function/TermStorage%3A%3AloadTree/8.4.x), without changing it.

```php
$terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree("myname");
```

Comment: That would certainly explain why I couldn't find one! Thanks, Clive!